# How do I find a String list's length in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I'm new to Java, and I'm certain I'm not using lists properly, but I'm saving loads of user input responses as elements of a String list (as a side question, do I want a String list or an array list for this task?), and I later want to print out these elements at the end of the program. However, I want to do this automatically through a for loop, but I don't know the length of the list to make the for loop do its job. I tried

```
for(int j = 0; j <= (results.length-1); j++){
```

where "results" is the name of the String list, but it's giving me the error "cannot find symbol." Is there any way to get the length of a String list in Java? And am I using the list thing properly, or should I be trying an array list instead? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the Javadoc of [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)? (I assume the compile-time type of `results` is List<String>`.) It's really important that you learn to read the appropriate documentation. Additionally, why have you tagged the question `arrays` when your question is about lists rather than arrays? It's important to understand that they're not the same thing. Finally, rather than saying `j <= results.length - 1` it would be more idiomatic to write `j < results.length`.

Comment: I do not know what "Javadoc" is. Sorry, I'm new to programming.

Comment: It's the documentation. I've linked to it in the comment.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Got it; I tagged "array" because it might pertain to array lists as well. I know lists and arrays are not the same thing, but I'm more familiar with arrays than I am lists, which is why I tried treating the String list like an array to get the length. But I'll look through this link and see if it fixes my issue. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Ray25Lee: "array lists" aren't arrays though - they're lists. `List<String>` and `ArrayList<String>` are very different from `String[]`, basically.

Comment: I know very well that lists aren't arrays, but aren't there array lists? Plus, lists are very new to me, and I don't know how to handle them. That's why I tried treating them like arrays syntax-wise to get the length. I didn't know of any other way to get the length, because I'm not familiar with the syntax of lists.

Answer (score 0):

If, by length, you mean the total number of elements contained in your list, you can use the `size()` method. It returns an integer that specifies the number of elements present in the list.

As for your `for` loop, you can do this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < results.size(); j++) {
//write loop logic here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
// add list elements using results.add("");

for( final String result : results )
{
   // process the results
   System.out.println( "Result: " + result );
}
```

Alternatively

```
//length of array list
int listLength = results.size();
for( int i = 0; i < listLength; i++ )
{
   System.out.println( "Result: " + results.get( i ) );
}
```

Comment: How does that help the OP know the length of the list? (The OP may want to put the index next to each result, for example.)

Comment: This will find the length of the list? Or does this just show how to make an array list? I can make an array list, I'm just wondering how to get the length of the String list I made, or if it's better to find the length with an array list.

Comment: The length of the list is given by the call to `results.size()`.

Comment: marstran, results.size() worked perfectly! Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed. I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
    // print result 31
    System.out.println("i hope you can have a nice day.".length()); 
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("i hope you can have");
    list.add(" a nice day");
    list.add(".");
    // [i hope you can have,  a nice day, .]
    System.out.println(list.toString()); 
    System.out.println(list.toString().length()-(list.size()-1)*2-2);
```